# Spalign package: the use of square brackets with the borders

Tags: matrices, brackets, delimiters

I am curious, since I have done several tests, how to set up the square brackets for the first matrix when I use the border with `spalign` package. I have seen this question and....actually I am not able to do it.

[Better spacing around brackets of kbordermatrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404538/better-spacing-around-brackets-of-kbordermatrix)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[\def\spalignendline{\cr}
\spalignrun{\bordermatrix{\the\spaligntoks}}
{, \scriptstyle{1} \scriptstyle{2}; \scriptstyle{1} 0 1; \scriptstyle{2} 1 0}\times \spaligndelims{[}{]} \spalignmat{a b; c d}=\spaligndelims{\{}{\}} \spalignmat{r t; s w}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa Hiii :-)...and thank you very much for your comment. I not know it. But after 8 years and 10 months ago, do I must necessary to use modification of `\bordermatrix`? sigh sigh....But in `spalign` package is recent...So is this package obsolete?

Comment: @campa spalign package. I have seen the documentation...October 5, 2016. See § 3 Implementation pag. 10.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's obsolete. It looks like it's been loaded on CTAN and never modified, so maybe it's unmantained, but it seems to be still working (I didn't know it so I have no experience with it). Regarding `\bordermatrix`: that's a plain TeX macro which has been copied into LaTeX and it will be likely never be modified. I see no trouble with making a copy changing the brackets, though I'd define my own version with interchangeable delimiters. But as you might have noticed I tend to use very few packages and write my own macros.

Comment: Wouldn't `nicematrix` be better?

Comment: @egreg Surely with nicematrix, but... I wanted get another answer using spalign package. The answer with nicematrix has been put from the maintainer of the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses are hard-coded in `\bordermatrix`. You could define a version with brackets explicitly as shown in [\bordermatrix with brackets [ ] instead of parentheses ( )](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55054/82917).

Alternatively, let us be lazy, copy the definition of `\bordermatrix`, and let `xpatch` replace the parentheses by brackets.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\let\bbordermatrix\bordermatrix
\xpatchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{(}{[}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{)}{]}{}{}

\begin{document}
\[
\def\spalignendline{\cr}\spaligndelims{[}{]}
\spalignrun{\bbordermatrix{\the\spaligntoks}}
{, \scriptstyle{1} \scriptstyle{2}; \scriptstyle{1} 0 1; \scriptstyle{2} 1 0}
\times
\spaligndelims{[}{]} \spalignmat{a b; c d}
=
\spaligndelims{\{}{\}} \spalignmat{r t; s w}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh..:-):-) Have you used a patch? ahahahhahah....You are clever ("furbo" in Italian language in a good sense of the word)  ahahah

Comment: Not "furbo". "Pigro". (I'm Italian too `;-)`)

Comment: Nooooooo it not possible `:-)`...I have seen Germany :-(((((

Answer (score 3):

For information, in `nicematrix`, you can easily write a command `\lightmatrix` to compose matrices with the syntax of `spalign` (thanks to the key `light-syntax` inspired by `spalign`) with the ability to use all the features of `nicematrix`, included exterior rows and columns (inspired by `\bordermatrix` and `kbordermatrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \lightmatrix } { D < > { p } O { } m } 
  {
    \group_begin:
    \NiceMatrixOptions { light-syntax }
    \begin { #1 NiceMatrix} [ #2 ]
    #3
    \end { #1 NiceMatrix }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle, 
    code-for-first-col = \scriptstyle,
  }

$\lightmatrix<b>[first-row,first-col]{ {}  1  2 ; 1  0  1 ; 2 1 0 }
\times
\lightmatrix{a  b ; c  d}
= 
\lightmatrix<B>{r  t ; s  w}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Very nice answer ..but you first matrix have not the square brackets with the labels out the matrix.

Comment: @Sebastiano: You are right. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Ah, don't worry. Please, what is the code to have the square brackets?

Comment: `\lightmatrix{...}` for rounded brackets (the default value), `\lightmatrix<b>{...}` for the square brackets, `\lightmatrix{B}` for curly braces, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much...and I have given a suggestion for a your recent answer. Excuse me with all my heart...but I give the check mark to @campa because is very closer to my question. But...I have given my grazie in another forms.